# Is there a libcurl max read size? Curl splits read into two parts

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

Is there a max size for reading that I am unaware of for curl? In my read function I receive my response in two separate calls to the function. I'm supposed to receive 24202 chars but I get it in 16384 and then 7818 instead of all characters in one go. What is the deal is there some way I can set it so that it happens all in one call to the write function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since you mention "receive my response" I assume you are talking about libcurl's write function.*

Indeed, the write callback API never exceeds `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE` bytes in one call
as documented [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION):

> `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`
>
> The maximum amount of body data that can be passed to the write
>   callback is defined in the `curl.h` header file: `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE`
>   (the usual default is `16K`).